# When calculating post percentage by tag, deleted posts are included in the numerator, but not the denominator

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, deleted-questions

[pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyspark) tag posts represent 117% of all [this user's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14498380/dataworld) posts:

[image]

Stats:

[image]

In user's profile it's seen that he has 0 answers and 6 questions. But in total it makes *7 posts*, as seen above.

Apparently, [the deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74007471/convert-a-string-value-into-date-format-in-pyspark) counts too, making the ratio

```
7 / 6 = 117%
```

It should probably be either 7/7 or 6/6.

Comment: Is this perhaps [caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/)? Maybe the calculation will be re-done without the deleted question. Eventually.

Comment: This is either fixed or it was indeed caching, since the calculation is correct now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXo5U.png It shows 8 posts 100% (the user posted one more question, the deleted question is still deleted).

Comment: @VLAZ: I'm seeing 114% for [pyspark] right now.

Comment: It's caching. We update the posts live but the deleted questions are only updated daily.

Comment: @V2Blast well...me too. Now. But that wasn't the case when I took the screenshot. I notice that they have 7 questions now, so one must have been deleted between me taking the screenshot and now. And the cache is again out of date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I explained how this works in an [answer to a duplicate on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371583/200-of-posts-with-this-tag/371690#371690):

> 1. Post counts aren't cached at all - this means that they will always be current.
> 2. Tag stats per user are only updated once per day - this means that any time someone deletes a post, the percentage will be off until the reset.
> 3. Cached number divided by an uncached number = Awesome high percentages!
>
> And... that's it.